# Serialize a form to localStorage / restore it after page reload (without jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, radio-button, local-storage

I have a `<form>` with a few radio buttons groups:

```html
<form>
Group 1: 
<input type='radio' name='a' value='1'>
<input type='radio' name='a' value='2'>
<input type='radio' name='a' value='3'><br>
Group 2: 
<input type='radio' name='b' value='1'>
<input type='radio' name='b' value='2'>
<input type='radio' name='b' value='3'>
</form>
```

**How to save, on each selection change event, everything to `localStorage`, and then on page reload (e.g. after we close and reopen the browser) reload the previously selected items?**

All what I think of for this seems unnecessarily complex.

We probably have to assign a listener to event "radio button is selected" or should we detect this simply with "change" event?

NB: This solves the similar problem for `<input type="text">`: [Auto-save all inputs value to localStorage and restore them on page reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61085148/auto-save-all-inputs-value-to-localstorage-and-restore-them-on-page-reload/61085307#61085307)

Maybe is there an easier way:

**Can we serialize a *whole* `<form>` state (input values, selected radio buttons, etc.) into `localStorage`, and easily restore it, without jQuery?** (without having to write specific code for text inputs, other code for radio buttons, other code for checkboxes, etc.)

Comment: To the downvoter: can you maybe add a comment to explain how to improve this question?

Comment: You use localStorage.setItem('key', value) and.getItem('key'). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17087636/how-to-save-data-from-a-form-with-html5-local-storage

Comment: @JoelHager this doesn't work so simply for `<input>` radio buttons group. Is there maybe a generic solution to serialize a whole `<form>`, no matter the content (radio, checkbox, text, etc.) ?

Comment: Maybe something like this? https://www.telerik.com/blogs/save-for-later-feature-in-forms-using-localstorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution for radio buttons:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]').forEach(elt => { 
    if (localStorage.getItem(elt.name) == elt.value) 
        elt.checked = true; 
    elt.addEventListener("change", e => { 
        localStorage.setItem(e.target.name, e.target.value); 
    }); 
});
```

This works for text `<input>`: [Auto-save all inputs value to localStorage and restore them on page reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61085148/auto-save-all-inputs-value-to-localstorage-and-restore-them-on-page-reload/61087013#61087013).

Comment: I would suggest running "formElement.querySelectorAll" instead of "document.querySelectorAll" because it will affect only inputs scoped within the form, not all inputs on the page.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a helper function to retrieve form values: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41262933/4988674
2. Add event listener to form changes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10760931/4988674
3. Inside event listener save form data into localStorage: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2010948/4988674
4. Create "onload" event and populate form values from localStorage: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7327185/4988674 and https://benalexkeen.com/autofilling-forms-with-javascript/

Comment: This works for `<input type="text">`, it's already done here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61085148/auto-save-all-inputs-value-to-localstorage-and-restore-them-on-page-reload/61085307#61085307. But here I'm looking for a generic way working for **all kind of inputs in a form (checkboxes, radio buttons, etc.)**.

Comment: Using plain Javascript you can't do it out-of-the-box in one line.

Comment: You can create this kind of generic "form filler" based on approach from the article from the last link (https://benalexkeen.com/autofilling-forms-with-javascript/).

Comment: Isn't there an automatic way with JSON.serialize a whole form @Max?

Comment: Looks like either this function may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/257401/4988674 or this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/6937576/4988674, but yeah, there is no commonly used utility for form population. Agree, it's pity.

Comment: I doubt this will work with radio buttons/checkboxes @Max: these codes don't use "checked" attribute which seems mandatory to persist the state of selected items.